# unable to change file permissions on external hard drive, 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, permissions, hard-drive

Ever since I changed over to 12.04 (Jul 2014) and then 14.04 (Aug) I have been unable to change the permissions of files on an external hard drive. Even though I am the owner and have rwx permission on both the drive and the folder that contains the file, I cannot make the file executable (even using sudo). I have tried to do so from the command line and in Nautilus. All executable files I copy to the drive, lose their executable status.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the drive formatted?

Comment: Is the drive mounted noexec ?

Comment: What does this show?: `mount | grep '^/dev/sdXN'` (with X and N replaced)

Comment: Volke, Bodi & Tim   /dev/sdd1 on /media/popsie/62090 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)  Would seem to indicated formatted for rw only. Yet, I successfully transferred files under 10.04